# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I need help with this issue. I am not sure what is wrong. This is the app level build gradle code. If I comment out other play services implementations it gives me other error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.rough.tuber.tuber"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    //    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
        implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0") {
            exclude group: "com.android.support"
        }
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please if I remove another play services in implementation then it gives me another error. I am not sure what to do.
I am adding more error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)

Comment: probably because of two `places` apis in gradle 
`implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'`
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'`

Remove first one

Comment: 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0' implementation remove this one?

Comment: yes. if it throws error share please

Comment: `//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'` comment this line and redesign your places class uses in app.

Comment: I have edited the question with error log but it still gives the same error. Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
@KuLdipPaTel

Comment: @rgaraisayev I shared the error by updating question.

Comment: `Program type already present` error basically happens when same two libs are in project. For another error, try cleaning and rebuilding project

Comment: either you have to use `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'` or `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'`.
 can't use both dependency at same time.

Comment: I did comment this one implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0' but still I am getting same error.

Comment: @rgaraisayev when I clean and rebuild after commenting one libs. I get the error I am updatinf error log in question.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: no @rgaraisayev I am getting this error. Program type already present: com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModule
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModule, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Answer (score 0):

try adding the code below in your (app) build.gradle file

```
configurations {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-places'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
}
```

and add the following to your dependencies {}

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
```

Comment: I am using this implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0' method for the maps auto search.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using seperate packages use the bundle.. it solve for me..

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```